# Probability of getting 4 Aces

Tags: combinatorics

What is the probability of drawing 4 aces from a standard deck of 52 cards. Is it:
$$
\frac{1}{52} \times \frac{1}{51} \times \frac{1}{50} \times \frac{1}{49} \times 4!
$$
or do I simply say it is:
$$
\frac{4}{52} = \frac{1}{13}
$$

Comment: The OP seems to give the right answer but then makes a mistake when simplifying. This assumes you take the first 4 cards without replacement from a well mixed deck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean getting 4 aces in a row when drawing them one by one from a full deck without replacement?

If it is the case, then it is simply multiplication of successive probabilities:

$\frac{4}{52}$ * $\frac{3}{51}$ * $\frac{2}{50}$ * $\frac{1}{49}$ = 
 4! * $\frac{48!}{52!}$ =  3.6938e-006.

Comment: removed comment duplicating what KC_CAL said

Comment: I get 1/270725 which is approximately 3.6 e-5. I say approximately because I did this by hand and not with a calculator.  This agrees with the above answer except for the far RHS.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer you provided ($\frac{1}{52}\times \frac{1}{51}\times \frac{1}{50}\times \frac{1}{49}\times 4!$) is correct.

If we draw four cards from 52 cards, then the total possible outcomes are $C_4^{52} 4!$.

The number of outcomes that have four aces in a row is $4!$

Thus the probability of drawing 4 aces from a standard deck of 52 cards is 
$$
\frac{4!}{C_4^{52} 4!} = \frac{1}{C_4^{52}} = \frac{4!}{52\times  51\times  50\times  49}
$$

Answer (score 1):

> What is the probability of drawing 4 aces from a standard deck of 52 cards

The correct answer to the question posed is: The probability is 1.

The other solutions posited on this page are solutions to a different question than that posed here.

Answer (score -1):

In a deck of cards what is the probability of getting 4 aces in the first 4 draws?

Answer: $4\times 4 = 16$

- $P(4\ {\rm aces}) = E=?\quad 16$
- $S=?\quad 52\times 51\times  50\times  49\quad (6,497,400) $
- $\frac{16}{6,497,400} = 0.000246\%$

Comment: The other answers all claim that the number of ways to get four aces in the first four draws is $4! = 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 24$. If you disagree on that point and somehow think it is actually $4 \cdot 4 = 16$ you need to back that statement up with some reasoning.

Comment: The other answers are all wrong. The correct answer is: the Probabiltiy is 1